# TypeError cannot read property url of undefined on strapi

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, next.js, strapi

I have a list of items. Some have a download link and some not.

If I try to render a an undefined url, I have this error. So I tried this :

```
if (spectacle.pdf.url) {
    const pdf = spectacle.pdf.url;
    const flag = `/fl_attachment:dossier${spectacle.slug}`;
    const position = 47;
    const output = [pdf.slice(0, position), flag, pdf.slice(position)].join('');
}
```

But I now have an other error telling me that output is not defined.
Does someone can explain me how to do it well to stop a function to load if undefined ?

[slug].js

```
const Spectacle = ({ spectacle, spectacles, categories }) => {



  const slideRight = () => {
    const slider = document.querySelector('.gallery');
    console.log(slider);
    slider.scrollBy({
      left: 450,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  }

  const slideLeft = () => {
    const slider = document.querySelector('.gallery');
    console.log(slider);
    slider.scrollBy({
      left: -450,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const bigTitle = document.getElementById('big-title');
    const vertTitle = document.getElementById('ver-title');
    const title = spectacle.title;
    if (title.length > 30) {
      bigTitle.style.fontSize = "8vw";
      vertTitle.style.fontSize = "3rem";
    }
  }, []);

  
if (spectacle.pdf.url) {
    const pdf = spectacle.pdf.url;
    const flag = `/fl_attachment:dossier${spectacle.slug}`;
    const position = 47;
    const output = [pdf.slice(0, position), flag, pdf.slice(position)].join('');
}


  return (
    <>
      <div className="spectacle-header">
        <img src={spectacle.image.url} />
        <div className="spectacle-titles">
          <h1 id="big-title" className="big-title">{spectacle.title}</h1>
          <h5 className="subtitle">{spectacle.sousTitre}</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Container className="spectacle-text">
        <Row className="bloc-mob">
          <Col className="ext a">
            <h1 id="ver-title" className="vertical-title red">{spectacle.title}</h1>
            <h2 className="quote shows">{spectacle.citation}</h2>
          </Col>
          <Col className="middle-col">
            <p className="">
              <Moment format="YYYY" className="date">{spectacle.year}</Moment>
            </p>
            <Row className="status">
              <Col>
                <span>{spectacle.status}</span>
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <span>{spectacle.category.name}</span>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <div>
              <p className="description" id='desc'>
                <ReactMarkdown source={spectacle.description} />
                <a href={output} download="newfilename"><h4>Télécharger le document</h4></a>
              </p>
              <div className="video"
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: spectacle.video}} >
              </div>
            </div>
          </Col>
          <Col className="ext b">
            <p className="generic" id="generic">
              <ReactMarkdown source={spectacle.cast} />
            </p>

           
            <div className="scroll-down">
              Scroll down
              <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/ciefact/image/upload/v1634668021/arrow_0e058f1520.svg"
                className="arrow-down" />
            </div>
          </Col>
          {/* <Col className="illu">
            <img src={spectacle.Illustration.url} />
          </Col> */}
        </Row>

        <Row className="gallery">

          {spectacle.galery.map((item) => (
            <ModalImage
              key={item.id}
              small={item.url}
              large={item.url}
              alt={item.title}
              hideZoom={true}
              hideDownload={true}
            />
          ))}
        </Row>
        <button
          id="slideLeft"
          type="button"
          onClick={slideLeft}
        >
          <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/ciefact/image/upload/v1634668021/arrow_0e058f1520.svg"
            className="arrow-down" />
        </button>
        <button
          id="slideRight"
          type="button"
          onClick={slideRight}
        >
          <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/ciefact/image/upload/v1634668021/arrow_0e058f1520.svg"
            className="arrow-down" />
        </button>
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const spectacles = await fetchAPI("/spectacles")

  return {
    paths: spectacles.map((spectacle) => ({
      params: {
        slug: spectacle.slug,
      },
    })),
    fallback: 'blocking',
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const spectacle = (await fetchAPI(`/spectacles?slug=${params.slug}`))[0]

  const [spectacles, categories] = await Promise.all([
    fetchAPI("/spectacles"),
    fetchAPI("/categories"),
  ])
  return {
    props: { spectacle: spectacle, spectacles, categories },
    revalidate: 1,
  }
}

export default Spectacle
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `output` inside your conditional block, so it's limited to that particular scope. You could declare it outside of the block and update it later.

This will cause issues with your download link still showing up even if no pdf is available, so you should probably hide or disable it when you don't have a pdf:

```js
const hasPdf = Boolean(spectacle.pdf.url);
let output;
if (hasPdf) {
  const pdf = spectacle.pdf.url;
  const flag = `/fl_attachment:dossier${spectacle.slug}`;
  const position = 47;
  output = [pdf.slice(0, position), flag, pdf.slice(position)].join('');
}
```

```js
{hasPdf && (
  <div>
    <p className="description" id="desc">
      <ReactMarkdown source={spectacle.description} />
      <a href={output} download="newfilename">
        <h4>Télécharger le document</h4>
      </a>
    </p>
    <div
      className="video"
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: spectacle.video }}
    />
  </div>
)}
```

Comment: It helps for the output problem, but I think as pdf.url is null, I still have the error when I don't have a link. Is it possible ?

Comment: Change the check to `const hasPdf = Boolean(spectacle.pdf?.url)`. Since the `pdf` property can be `undefined`, using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) should fix the issue.

Comment: My mistake this was spectacle.pdf that was null. So ```const hasPdf = Boolean(spectacle.pdf)```was right. 
Thank you very much